# Is it possible to add a child element created in a separate cs

Tags: c#

I'm still fairly new to programming and don't really get how to outsource the load to other class1.cs. I'm wondering if is possible to create say a button or a label in another .cs and grid.Children.add(//Button);?

This is where I'm at so far.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace IconManager
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Test NewTest;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewTest = new Test();
            NewTest.some();
        }
    }
}

using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace IconManager
{
    class Test : MainWindow
    {
        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        public void some()
        {
            Button Zan = new Button() { Height = 100, Width = 100, Background = Brushes.Black };
            grid.Children.Add(Zan);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this was something I also struggeld with starting programming in WPF. Generally speaking learning more about frontend patterns like MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) and MVC (Model-View-Controller) helped me a lot to structure my applications.

But to start with your very problem let me say this: It's possible to pass windows or viewcontainer along to other classes. For example you could do the following:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var mainWindowFiller = new MainWindwoFiller(this.mainGrid);
    }
}
```

Please note here, that I named my grid in MainWindow with x:Name="mainGrid".
The MainWindowFiller can then do stuff like this:

```
 public class MainWindwoFiller
{
    private readonly Grid _mainGrid;

    public MainWindwoFiller(Grid mainGrid)
    {
        _mainGrid = mainGrid;
        FillMainWindowGrid();
    }

    private void FillMainWindowGrid()
    {
        var button = new Button();
        button.Click += Button_Click;
        _mainGrid.Children.Add(button);
        _mainGrid.Children.Add(new Label()
            {
                Content = "Label"
            }
        );
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click!");
    }
}
```

In this example, two simple UI Elements are added to the Grid. You can actually do everything in here like deleting the grid and add a canvas or add new events. Actually everything you could do in MainWindow.xaml.cs.

However, even if this should solve your immediate problem, it's not the recommended Way to go. I mostly work with the MVVM pattern and there it's recommended to use bindings in your views (views are basically all containers which are containing visual elements like Window or UserControl). With bindings you can use the properties and commands in another class. But to make it more visible here a little example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d" DataContext="MainWindowViewModel"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
       <Label Height="80" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,100,0,0" Content="{Binding LabelText}"/>
       <Button x:Name="MainWindowButton" Height="40" Width="120" Content="{Binding ButtonText}" Click="MainWindowButton_OnClick"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The corresponding xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindowButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainWindowViewModel)this.DataContext).ButtonClickEvent();
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Click Me";
    public string LabelText { get; set; } = "Sir ReadALot";

    public void ButtonClickEvent()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click!");
    }
}
```

And from the ViewModel you could now access Data or connect to a backend service. But with this kind of structure you should be able to overcome most challenges. If you want to have changeable properties you will need INotifyPropertyChanged later on. But that's a different topic. I hope that helps you to go on step further on your developer way.
Cheers!

Comment: I find Wpf is really helpful for visual learning, but a pain when finding methods, the results usually show windows forms which tends to work but there is always something that's not compatible. That said, I'll check out MVVM since you mentioned it. And thank you! this really helped me out.

Comment: Oh and if it not too much to ask. I used your first method and I was able to create an event handler too in "MainWindowFiller." Would there also be a way to direct the event handler back to MainWindow?

Comment: First to your question: You can always create methods which have the desired return values or if its already a known event handler you create a public field/property inside the class, initialize it in the constructor and access it in the MainWindow.xaml.cs class like MainWindFiller.Button1EventHandler. I also updated my solution to show how I would implement a button click with the first way. However, great that I could help you :) I hope you will have fun with wpf and have s steep learning curve. If you liked my answer I would appreciate a up vote.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. You have been a huge help. And I trying was to vote but I couldn't figure out how to do so, I will figure that out later and leave you one when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Part of xaml file:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Add new button</Button>
</Grid>
```

Part of MainWindow file:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyButton.AddButtonToGrid(this.Grid);
}
```

Part of MyButton.cs file:

```
public static class MyButton
{
    public static void AddButtonToGrid(Grid grid)
    {
        Button myButton = new Button()
        {
            Height = 100,
            Width = 100,
            Background = Brushes.Black
        };
        grid.Children.Add(myButton);
    }
}
```

Does this answer your question?